# Reading files using PHPExcel in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, phpexcel, cakephp-3.0, autoload

I've installed PHPExcel into a CakePHP 3 project using Composer. I'm not sure how much autoloading I should be getting, or how to go about 'fixing' things (this is my first look at CakePHP 3, although used version 2 quite a bit). If I have this in a file:

```
use PHPExcel;
```

I can then do this:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
```

However, I'd like to read a file, so I *think* I want to do:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);
```

but that gives:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Shell\PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found in...
```

Should I just require_once the file with that class in, or is there a fancier, autoload way of making this class available?

Comment: You are using `use` for `PHPExcel`, so maybe for `PHPExcel_IOFactory` you shoud ...

Comment: Genius - I am a fool. If you want to add that as an answer I can accept it? And thanks!

Comment: Namespaces and use statements are PHP things, BTW, not CakePHP specific.

Comment: i added PHPExcel using composer but when i load PHPExcel` on my controller with required_once and use like `use PHPExcel;` it does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
PHPExcel_IOFactory;
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This isn't much of an answer. Please see "[answer]".